# Create polygon around specific OSM tags

Tags: openstreetmap, osmium

I have a OSM file (http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/malta-latest.osm.pbf). I am only interested in data that are around ramps (motorway_link,trunk_link,primary_link,secondary_link,tertiary_link) as in the picture. Therefore I want to preprocess the data to keep the OSM file as small as possible. I use the osmium tool.

I want to do it as followed, but I do not know how to implement **step 2**:

1. Filter pbf file by desired tags -> malta-ramps.osm.pbf

```
osmium tags-filter -v --overwrite -o malta-ramps.osm.pbf malta-latest.osm.pbf w/highway=motorway_link,trunk_link,primary_link,secondary_link,tertiary_link
```

2. Create polygons around the filteres data -> malta-polygons.poly

```
How to create the buffered polygons around the ramps e.g. with python?
```

3. Cut out the polygons from the original OSM file -> malta-finished.osm.pbf

```
osmium extract --overwrite -p malta-polygons.poly -o malta-finished.osm.pbf malta-latest.osm.pbf
```

[image]

Comment: here an approach:
convert lines to GeoJSON `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON lines.geojson malta-ramps.osm.pbf lines` - compute a buffer `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON buffer.geojson lines.gpkg -dialect sqlite -sql "select st_buffer(geom, 0.0001) from lines" ` **NOTE** the buffer distance is in degrees, which is quite hacky. To use metric distance you need to transform to a metric CRS like UTM.  Then you might union the buffered polygons to prevent overlap. Finally convert the polygons to a format osmium understand as describe here https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/manual.html#creating-geographic-extracts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this:

1. Convert from *pbf* to *geojson* -> malta-ramps.geojson
   `osmium export malta-ramps.osm.pbf -o malta-ramps.geojson -O`
2. Extract unioned polygons (for all geometries) -> malta-polygons.geojson
   `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON malta-polygons.geojson malta-ramps.geojson -dialect sqlite -sql "select st_union(st_buffer(geometry, 0.002)) from malta-ramps"`

Comment: Keep in mind, that buffering with latitude/longitude is super hacky and might only work for your area of interest. It would be much cleaner to reproject your data to metric system (e.g.[UTM](https://epsg.io/32632)) first. Something like: `ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:32632 malta-ramps-utm.geojson malta-ramps.geojson` , Union with `st_buffer(geometry, 100)` with 100 meters, convert it back to lat/lon `ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 final_result.geojson malta-ramps-buffer.geojson` moreover, the shape of the result should be much more circular and less ellipse shaped